# How do I delete an Outlook calendar entry (after the meeting is over) without notifying the creator

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

I have several meetings during the day and I like to be able to open my calendar and see what is left at a glance so I delete the meetings that I have already completed.  If I do this close enough to the meeting time I am asked if I want to notify the creator.  If I do this after the meeting has started Outlook automatically sends a notice to the creator that I have declined the meeting.  I am only deleting the one instance so it is still in my calendar for the next time, however that creates an email that others must read/delete.

**I need to be able to remove single occurrences of meetings without automatically sending a notice that I am deleting the entry.**

NOTE: I am using Outlook 2007, I did not see anything in the Advanced Email Options.

NOTE 2: I have seen this happen with Lotus notes as well (Like anyone actually uses that).

NOTE 3: There is not a sent message created, only the creator of the calendar event will see the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying to do this. I gave up on finding a way to prevent the email and just dismiss the event. I found the best way to do what I want was just to adjust how I look at the calendar as a whole. Instead of looking at the entire day I now just look at the current time marker and see what the day has left.

Thank you Debra for attempting to find a solution.

Comment: You're welcome, and sorry it didn't work out for you. I've been working for a company that uses Notes, which really is worse about this (if possible). But Groupwise is the only client I know of that handles it differently.

Comment: The other [answer](https://superuser.com/a/810600/494173) with Working Offline works.

Answer (score 1):

Change your calender to list view, select the meeting/s and press the delete key.

Comment: I did a test and it still sends the email.

Answer (score 1):

Go offline.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/switch-between-working-offline-and-online-HP001232960.aspx

Delete Meeting.

Delete email from Outbox.

Comment: I don't see an email in my Outbox when I do this, so maybe it skips the sending the email if working offline. This works though. Thanks!